# Search in webserver logs with grep and save results to file

Tags: linux, grep

I'm looking for all the activities of a particular person with a specific ip in a huge access log and save the results into a text file.

What I'm currently doing in Ubuntu Server is:

```
grep "255.255.255.255" access.log >> search.txt
```

which gives me no results! but I'm sure there are hundreds of activity by this ip in my log.

What is wrong with my command?

**Update:** here is some exmples of my access log (sorry I can't show the actual ip addresses and my domain name):

```
37.98.x.x - - [27/Aug/2013:18:46:34 +0430] "GET /stats/piwik.php?action_name=%D8%AA%D8%A7%D9%85%20%D9%88%20%D8%AC%D8%B1%DB%8C&idsite=1&rec=1&r=414317&h=18&m=46&s=45&url=http%3A%2F%2Fpooyatv.ir%2F%25D8%25A8%25D8%25B1%25D9%2586%25D8%25A7%25D9%2585%25D9%2587%25E2%2580%258C%25D9%2587%25D8%25A7%2Fitem%2F26-%25D8%25AA%25D8%25A7%25D9%2585-%25D9%2588-%25D8%25AC%25D8%25B1%25DB%258C&urlref=http%3A%2F%2Fpooyatv.ir%2F&_id=3cbd28047168de3d&_idts=1377354671&_idvc=5&_idn=0&_refts=0&_viewts=1377530242&pdf=1&qt=0&realp=0&wma=1&dir=0&fla=1&java=1&gears=0&ag=0&cookie=1&res=1024x768&gt_ms=649 HTTP/1.1" 200 269 "http://mysite.ir/%D8%A8%D8%B1%D9%86%D8%A7%D9%85%D9%87%E2%80%8C%D9%87%D8%A7/item/26-%D8%AA%D8%A7%D9%85-%D9%88-%D8%AC%D8%B1%DB%8C" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.95 Safari/537.36"
2.144.x.x - - [27/Aug/2013:18:46:35 +0430] "GET /media/galleries/409/14.jpg HTTP/1.1" 304 190 "http://mysite.ir/%D8%A8%D8%B1%D9%86%D8%A7%D9%85%D9%87%E2%80%8C%D9%87%D8%A7/item/409-%D8%A8%D8%A7%D8%A8-%D8%A7%D8%B3%D9%81%D9%86%D8%AC%DB%8C" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:2.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0"
37.98.x.x - - [27/Aug/2013:18:46:34 +0430] "GET /media/items/cache/feb4274796d93ff716e9650163a77fb8_XL.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 53717 "http://mysite.ir/%D8%A8%D8%B1%D9%86%D8%A7%D9%85%D9%87%E2%80%8C%D9%87%D8%A7/item/26-%D8%AA%D8%A7%D9%85-%D9%88-%D8%AC%D8%B1%DB%8C" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.95 Safari/537.36"
95.38.x.x - - [27/Aug/2013:18:46:36 +0430] "GET /cache/jw_sigpro/jwsigpro_cache_d9f361e470_42.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 4679 "http://www.poyatv.ir/\xc8\xd1\xe4\xc7\xe3\xe5\x9d\xe5\xc7/item/53461-\xdd\xe6\xca\xc8\xc7\xe1\xed\xd3\xca-\xe5\xc7" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; InfoPath.2)"
91.99.x.x - - [27/Aug/2013:18:46:36 +0430] "GET /media/k2/items/cache/245effadf41c6129f4fe7accc564ef86_S.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 7589 "http://www.mysite.ir/%D8%A8%D8%B1%D9%86%D8%A7%D9%85%D9%87%E2%80%8C%D9%87%D8%A7/item/651-%D8%B3%DB%8C%D9%86%D9%85%D8%A7%DB%8C%DB%8C-%D8%A8%D8%A7%D8%A8-%D8%A7%D8%B3%D9%81%D9%86%D8%AC%DB%8C" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:23.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/23.0"
5.113.x.x - - [27/Aug/2013:18:46:36 +0430] "GET /cache/jw_sigpro/jwsigpro_cache_0f4194d152_6.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 10693 "http://mysite.ir/%D8%A8%D8%B1%D9%86%D8%A7%D9%85%D9%87%E2%80%8C%D9%87%D8%A7/item/52604-%D8%A8%D8%A7%D8%A8%D8%A7-%D9%84%D9%86%DA%AF-%D8%AF%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%B2" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:23.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/23.0"
46.225.x.x - - [27/Aug/2013:18:46:34 +0430] "GET /images/backgrounds/painting_bg.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 41400 "http://www.mysite.ir/upload-center" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; InfoPath.2; AskTbPTV2/5.15.15.35882)"
151.241.x.x - - [27/Aug/2013:18:46:36 +0430] "GET /index.php?option=com_k2&view=item&task=vote&format=raw&user_rating=5&itemID=240 HTTP/1.1" 200 343 "http://www.mysite.ir/%D8%A8%D8%B1%D9%86%D8%A7%D9%85%D9%87%E2%80%8C%D9%87%D8%A7/item/240-%D8%AE%D8%A7%D9%86%D8%AF%D8%A7%D9%86-%D9%BE%D9%87%D9%84%D9%88%DB%8C" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.57 Safari/537.36"
```

**Update 2:** When I search for example for `192.168` it finds every row containing it like `192.168.150.160`, but if I search for `192.168.150.160` it returns nothing!

Comment: Can you provide some rows with that 'IP'? (255.255.255.255 can not point to valid IP)

Comment: I just wanted to show my command, this is not the actual ip.

Comment: Your syntax seems to be right, so, anyway, provide some data

Comment: I updated my question with some log examples

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your command that would cause the problem you describe. For us to help you you'll need to provide some sample input with IP addresses (make them up) in it and copy/paste what happens when you run your command on that input file so we can see in what way it is failing. Do one thing though - run `cat -v` on your input file to see if it has trailing control-Ms on each line as it would if it was created on Windows. If it does, then run `dos2unix` onthe file to fix that.

Comment: @EdMorton I'm sure there is nothing wrong with log file and my command doesn't come with any errors. It just returns no results. I made an update to my question, I hope it helps.